# Unable to post data from form to mysql in Angular 2

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I am able to fetch the value I add in my textbox in a variable in my `addoperation.ts` file, but I am unable to send it to my database.

Here is my `addoperation.ts` code:

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Headers, Http, HttpModule ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-operationadd',
  templateUrl: './operationadd.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operationadd.component.css']
})
export class OperationaddComponent implements OnInit {

 name="abc";
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submitdata(){
    console.log("Data Submitted");
    console.log(this.name);
   this.http.post('http://example.com/adv8/prod-api/crudtable-add.php', {name: this.name})
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(result =>{          });
  }

}
```

and this is my `addoperation.html`

```
 <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  #fname [(ngModel)]="name" name="firstname">
  </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="submitdata()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My API is working fine, I have tested it on Chrome Postman. I pass a variable `name: jess` in the body and I get a SUCCESS message, but I am unable to save it from Angular.

Comment: Your `subscribe` block is blank. Is this a typo? `.subscribe(result =>{          });`

Comment: i am new to angular , i am just trying to copy and test from posts, what should be added here ?

Comment: my goal is to save the value in `name` parameter in my db, when its posting , its creating 2 records dont know why and name field is coming  empty, let me show how in postman it works and how its behaving in angular...making a video for you

Comment: Here is the video - http://youtu.be/5mPTkPkLRMs?hd=1

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search i am able to post the data in my db, below I am pasting code , should be useful to someone in future.

Note: adding headers is important.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Headers, Http, HttpModule ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-operationadd',
  templateUrl: './operationadd.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operationadd.component.css']
})
export class OperationaddComponent implements OnInit {

 name="abc";
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submitdata(){
    console.log("Data Submitted");
    console.log(this.name);
var body = "name=" + this.name;
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

 this.http.post('http://example.com/adv8/prod-api/crudtable-add.php', body, {
    headers: headers
    })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
     // data => this.saveJwt(data.id_token),
     // err => this.logError(err),
      () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
    );
}


}
```